# Allow other users (Adviser) to access MY APP

Tags: web-applications, xero-api

I have created an app and have invited my colleague to work on this app together. How do I add grant access to my colleague to view my app logs and history?
[Log & History screenshot from XERO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBMqN.png)

Comment: This is a very vague question. How are your logs stored? Where are they stored? What are you "granting privileges" to? A server? This question cannot be answered without further information.

Comment: @tedtanner
1.  granting colleage to XERO APP which will allows them to access the Log & History page of XERO

Answer (score 1):

You can add up to 20 collaborators to your app

I have added a link below with more details.

Xero Developer Centre: [Collaborators](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/collaborators/overview/#overview)